# how to make a function recursive

Tags: python, function, recursion, python-3.x

i have this huge function and i am wondering how to make it recursive. i have the base case which should never come true, so it should always go to else and keep calling itself with the variable t increases. any help would be great
thanks

```
 def draw(x, y, t, planets):
    if 'Satellites' in planets["Moon"]:
        print ("fillcircle", x, y, planets["Moon"]['Radius']*scale)
    else:
            print("refresh")
            print("colour 0 0 0")
            print("clear")
            print("colour 255 255 255")
            print("fillcircle",x,y,planets['Sun']['Radius']*scale)
            print("text ", "\"Sun\"",x+planets['Sun']['Radius']*scale,y)
            if "Mercury" in planets:
                r_Mercury=planets['Mercury']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",x,y,r_Mercury)
                r_Xmer=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mercury']['Period'])*r_Mercury
                r_Ymer=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mercury']['Period'])*r_Mercury
                print("fillcircle",r_Xmer,r_Ymer,3)
                print("text ", "\"Mercury\"",r_Xmer+planets['Mercury']['Radius']*scale,r_Ymer)
            if "Venus" in planets:
                r_Venus=planets['Venus']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",x,y,r_Venus)
                r_Xven=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Venus']['Period'])*r_Venus
                r_Yven=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Venus']['Period'])*r_Venus
                print("fillcircle",r_Xven,r_Yven,3)
                print("text ", "\"Venus\"",r_Xven+planets['Venus']['Radius']*scale,r_Yven)
            if "Earth" in planets:
                r_Earth=planets['Earth']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",x,y,r_Earth)
                r_Xe=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Earth']['Period'])*r_Earth
                r_Ye=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Earth']['Period'])*r_Earth
                print("fillcircle",r_Xe,r_Ye,3)
                print("text ", "\"Earth\"",r_Xe+planets['Earth']['Radius']*scale,r_Ye)
            if "Moon" in planets:
                r_Moon=planets['Moon']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xe,r_Ye,r_Moon)
                r_Xm=r_Xe+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Moon']['Period'])*r_Moon
                r_Ym=r_Ye+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Moon']['Period'])*r_Moon
                print("fillcircle",r_Xm,r_Ym,3)
                print("text ", "\"Moon\"",r_Xm+planets['Moon']['Radius']*scale,r_Ym)
            if "Mars" in planets:
                r_Mars=planets['Mars']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",x,y,r_Mars)
                r_Xmar=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mars']['Period'])*r_Mars
                r_Ymar=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mars']['Period'])*r_Mars
                print("fillcircle",r_Xmar,r_Ymar,3)
                print("text ", "\"Mars\"",r_Xmar+planets['Mars']['Radius']*scale,r_Ymar)
            if "Phobos" in planets:
                r_Phobos=planets['Phobos']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xmar,r_Ymar,r_Phobos)
                r_Xpho=r_Xmar+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Phobos']['Period'])*r_Phobos
                r_Ypho=r_Ymar+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Phobos']['Period'])*r_Phobos
                print("fillcircle",r_Xpho,r_Ypho,3)
                print("text ", "\"Phobos\"",r_Xpho+planets['Phobos']['Radius']*scale,r_Ypho)
            if "Deimos" in planets:
                r_Deimos=planets['Deimos']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xmar,r_Ymar,r_Deimos)
                r_Xdei=r_Xmar+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Deimos']['Period'])*r_Deimos
                r_Ydei=r_Ymar+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Deimos']['Period'])*r_Deimos
                print("fillcircle",r_Xdei,r_Ydei,3)
                print("text ", "\"Deimos\"",r_Xpho+planets['Deimos']['Radius']*scale,r_Ydei)
            if "Ceres" in planets:
                r_Ceres=planets['Ceres']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",x,y,r_Ceres)
                r_Xcer=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ceres']['Period'])*r_Ceres
                r_Ycer=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ceres']['Period'])*r_Ceres
                print("fillcircle",r_Xcer,r_Ycer,3)
                print("text ", "\"Ceres\"",r_Xcer+planets['Ceres']['Radius']*scale,r_Ycer)
            if "Jupiter" in planets:
                r_Jupiter=planets['Jupiter']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",x,y,r_Jupiter)
                r_Xjup=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Jupiter']['Period'])*r_Jupiter
                r_Yjup=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Jupiter']['Period'])*r_Jupiter
                print("fillcircle",r_Xjup,r_Yjup,3)
                print("text ", "\"Jupiter\"",r_Xjup+planets['Jupiter']['Radius']*scale,r_Yjup)
            if "Io" in planets:
                r_Io=planets['Io']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xjup,r_Yjup,r_Io)
                r_Xio=r_Xjup+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Io']['Period'])*r_Io
                r_Yio=r_Yjup+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Io']['Period'])*r_Io
                print("fillcircle",r_Xio,r_Yio,3)
                print("text ", "\"Io\"",r_Xio+planets['Io']['Radius']*scale,r_Yio)
            if "Europa" in planets:
                r_Europa=planets['Europa']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xjup,r_Yjup,r_Europa)
                r_Xeur=r_Xjup+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Europa']['Period'])*r_Europa
                r_Yeur=r_Yjup+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Europa']['Period'])*r_Europa
                print("fillcircle",r_Xeur,r_Yeur,3)
                print("text ", "\"Europa\"",r_Xeur+planets['Europa']['Radius']*scale,r_Yeur)
            if "Ganymede" in planets:
                r_Ganymede=planets['Ganymede']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xjup,r_Yjup,r_Ganymede)
                r_Xgan=r_Xjup+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ganymede']['Period'])*r_Ganymede
                r_Ygan=r_Yjup+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ganymede']['Period'])*r_Ganymede
                print("fillcircle",r_Xgan,r_Ygan,3)
                print("text ", "\"Ganymede\"",r_Xgan+planets['Ganymede']['Radius']*scale,r_Ygan)
            if "Callisto" in planets:
                r_Callisto=planets['Callisto']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xjup,r_Yjup,r_Callisto)
                r_Xcal=r_Xjup+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Callisto']['Period'])*r_Callisto
                r_Ycal=r_Yjup+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Callisto']['Period'])*r_Callisto
                print("fillcircle",r_Xcal,r_Ycal,3)
                print("text ", "\"Callisto\"",r_Xcal+planets['Callisto']['Radius']*scale,r_Ycal)
            if "Saturn" in planets:
                r_Saturn=planets['Saturn']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",x,y,r_Saturn)
                r_Xsat=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Saturn']['Period'])*r_Saturn
                r_Ysat=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Saturn']['Period'])*r_Saturn
                print("fillcircle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,3)
                print("text ", "\"Saturn\"",r_Xsat+planets['Saturn']['Radius']*scale,r_Ysat)
            if "Mimas" in planets:
                r_Mimas=planets['Mimas']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Mimas)
                r_Xmim=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mimas']['Period'])*r_Mimas
                r_Ymim=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mimas']['Period'])*r_Mimas
                print("fillcircle",r_Xmim,r_Ymim,3)
                print("text ", "\"Mimas\"",r_Xmim+planets['Mimas']['Radius']*scale,r_Ymim)
            if "Enceladus" in planets:
                r_Enceladus=planets['Enceladus']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Enceladus)
                r_Xenc=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Enceladus']['Period'])*r_Enceladus
                r_Yenc=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Enceladus']['Period'])*r_Enceladus
                print("fillcircle",r_Xenc,r_Yenc,3)
                print("text ", "\"Enceladus\"",r_Xenc+planets['Enceladus']['Radius']*scale,r_Yenc)
            if "Tethys" in planets:
                r_Tethys=planets['Tethys']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Tethys)
                r_Xtet=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Tethys']['Period'])*r_Tethys
                r_Ytet=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Tethys']['Period'])*r_Tethys
                print("fillcircle",r_Xtet,r_Ytet,3)
                print("text ", "\"Tethys\"",r_Xtet+planets['Tethys']['Radius']*scale,r_Ytet)
            if "Dione" in planets:
                r_Dione=planets['Dione']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Dione)
                r_Xdio=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Dione']['Period'])*r_Dione
                r_Ydio=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Dione']['Period'])*r_Dione
                print("fillcircle",r_Xdio,r_Ydio,3)
                print("text ", "\"Dione\"",r_Xdio+planets['Dione']['Radius']*scale,r_Ydio)
            if "Rhea" in planets:
                r_Rhea=planets['Rhea']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Rhea)
                r_Xrhe=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Rhea']['Period'])*r_Rhea
                r_Yrhe=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Rhea']['Period'])*r_Rhea
                print("fillcircle",r_Xrhe,r_Yrhe,3)
                print("text ", "\"Rhea\"",r_Xrhe+planets['Rhea']['Radius']*scale,r_Yrhe)
            if "Titan" in planets:
                r_Titan=planets['Titan']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Titan)
                r_Xtit=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titan']['Period'])*r_Titan
                r_Ytit=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titan']['Period'])*r_Titan
                print("fillcircle",r_Xtit,r_Ytit,3)
                print("text ", "\"Titan\"",r_Xtit+planets['Titan']['Radius']*scale,r_Ytit)
            if "Iapetus" in planets:
                r_Iapetus=planets['Iapetus']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Iapetus)
                r_Xiap=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Iapetus']['Period'])*r_Iapetus
                r_Yiap=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Iapetus']['Period'])*r_Iapetus
                print("fillcircle",r_Xiap,r_Yiap,3)
                print("text ", "\"Iapetus\"",r_Xiap+planets['Iapetus']['Radius']*scale,r_Yiap)
            if "Uranus" in planets:
                r_Uranus=planets['Uranus']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",x,y,r_Uranus)
                r_Xura=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Uranus']['Period'])*r_Uranus
                r_Yura=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Uranus']['Period'])*r_Uranus
                print("fillcircle",r_Xura,r_Yura,3)
                print("text ", "\"Uranus\"",r_Xura+planets['Uranus']['Radius']*scale,r_Yura)
            if "Puck" in planets:
                r_Puck=planets['Puck']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Puck)
                r_Xpuc=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Puck']['Period'])*r_Puck
                r_Ypuc=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Puck']['Period'])*r_Puck
                print("fillcircle",r_Xpuc,r_Ypuc,3)
                print("text ", "\"Puck\"",r_Xpuc+planets['Puck']['Radius']*scale,r_Ypuc)
            if "Miranda" in planets:
                r_Miranda=planets['Miranda']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Miranda)
                r_Xmira=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Miranda']['Period'])*r_Miranda
                r_Ymira=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Miranda']['Period'])*r_Miranda
                print("fillcircle",r_Xmira,r_Ymira,3)
                print("text ", "\"Miranda\"",r_Xmira+planets['Miranda']['Radius']*scale,r_Ymira)
            if "Ariel" in planets:
                r_Ariel=planets['Ariel']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Ariel)
                r_Xari=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ariel']['Period'])*r_Ariel
                r_Yari=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ariel']['Period'])*r_Ariel
                print("fillcircle",r_Xari,r_Yari,3)
                print("text ", "\"Ariel\"",r_Xari+planets['Ariel']['Radius']*scale,r_Yari)
            if "Umbriel" in planets:
                r_Umbriel=planets['Umbriel']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Umbriel)
                r_Xumb=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Umbriel']['Period'])*r_Umbriel
                r_Yumb=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Umbriel']['Period'])*r_Umbriel
                print("fillcircle",r_Xumb,r_Yumb,3)
                print("text ", "\"Umbriel\"",r_Xumb+planets['Umbriel']['Radius']*scale,r_Yumb)
            if "Titania" in planets:
                r_Titania=planets['Titania']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Titania)
                r_Xtita=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titania']['Period'])*r_Titania
                r_Ytita=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titania']['Period'])*r_Titania
                print("fillcircle",r_Xtita,r_Ytita,3)
                print("text ", "\"Titania\"",r_Xtita+planets['Titania']['Radius']*scale,r_Ytita)
            if "Oberon" in planets:
                r_Oberon=planets['Oberon']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Oberon)
                r_Xober=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Oberon']['Period'])*r_Oberon
                r_Yober=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Oberon']['Period'])*r_Oberon
                print("fillcircle",r_Xober,r_Yober,3)
                print("text ", "\"Oberon\"",r_Xober+planets['Oberon']['Radius']*scale,r_Yober)
            if "Neptune" in planets:
                r_Neptune=planets['Neptune']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",x,y,r_Neptune)
                r_Xnep=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Neptune']['Period'])*r_Neptune
                r_Ynep=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Neptune']['Period'])*r_Neptune
                print("fillcircle",r_Xnep,r_Ynep,3)
                print("text ", "\"Neptune\"",r_Xnep+planets['Neptune']['Radius']*scale,r_Ynep)
            if "Titan" in planets:
                r_Titan=planets['Titan']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle",r_Xnep,r_Ynep,r_Titan)
                r_Xtita=r_Xnep+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titan']['Period'])*r_Titan
                r_Ytita=r_Ynep+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titan']['Period'])*r_Titan
                print("fillcircle",r_Xtita,r_Ytita,3)
                print("text ", "\"Titan\"",r_Xtita+planets['Titan']['Radius']*scale,r_Ytita)

            t += 0.003
            draw(x, y, t, planets)
def draw(x, y, t, planets):
    if 'Satellites' in planets["Moon"]:
        print ("fillcircle", x, y, planets["Moon"]['Radius']*scale)
    else:
        print("refresh")
        print("colour 0 0 0")
        print("clear")
        print("colour 255 255 255")
        print("fillcircle",x,y,planets['Sun']['Radius']*scale)
        print("text ", "\"Sun\"",x+planets['Sun']['Radius']*scale,y)

        for each in planets.keys():
                r_planet=planets[each]['Orbital Radius']*scale;
                print("circle", x, y, r_planet)
                #if "Period" in planets[each]:
                    #r_X = x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets[each]['Period'])*r_planet
                    #r_Y = y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets[each]['Period'])*r_planet
                    #print("fillcircle",r_X,r_Y,3)
                    #print("text ", each, r_X+planets[each]['Radius']*scale,r_Y)
                    #t += 0.003

print(draw(x, y, t, planets))
```

i trimmed down the draw to the above it calculates where the circle goes but doesnt print it in quickdraw??

Comment: You should have some base case. Otherwise the recursion would never terminate

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of this type of question here lately. Is this homework?

Comment: i dont want it to terminate because the animation is continuous

Comment: If it doesn't terminate, your program will run out of stack space and will crash. Then you won't be able to draw those nice little heavenly bodies.

Comment: lol true any suggestions for me?

Comment: I'm confused by the fact that your sample code has two `draw()` function definitions in it followed by a call to second one (since that one replaced the first when it was defined). The first one is recursive in the sense that it calls itself, but it is never called If it was, it would loop forever since the call to itself passes almost exactly the same arguments as the initial call except `t` has been incremented. A recursive function should have some sort of stop condition when it quits calling itself. I don't think this was the sort of recursion they had in mind for your assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should define the sun first outside your recursive function because the sun is fixed anyway.

e.g.

```
        print("fillcircle",400,200,planets['Sun']['Radius']*scale)
        print("text ", "\"Sun\"",x+planets['Sun']['Radius']*scale,y)
             def planets:
                    if ~~~~~
```

the scale should be defined as well.

Comment: yeah do know how i would call my fucntion ??

Comment: you already called it at the end

Comment: what error are you getting? if thats the problem.

Comment: no error the function jus wont run

Comment: in quickdraw? does it still print values?

Comment: when i dont pipe it to quickdraw it doesnt even run the draw unction

Comment: nothing at all?! but it looks like you called it at the end... is your indent correct?

Comment: i believe its just like the long programabove

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20056/discussion-between-romulus-and-tom-smith)

Answer (score 3):

If indeed you want the base case to fail, then your function needs to call your function again:

```
def draw(x, y, t, planets):
    if 'Satellites' in planets["Moon"]:
        print ("fillcircle", x, y, planets["Moon"]['Radius']*scale)
    else:
        print("refresh")
        print("colour 0 0 0")
        print("clear")
        print("colour 255 255 255")
        print("fillcircle",x,y,planets['Sun']['Radius']*scale)
        print("text ", "\"Sun\"",x+planets['Sun']['Radius']*scale,y)
        if "Mercury" in planets:
            r_Mercury=planets['Mercury']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",x,y,r_Mercury)
            r_Xmer=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mercury']['Period'])*r_Mercury
            r_Ymer=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mercury']['Period'])*r_Mercury
            print("fillcircle",r_Xmer,r_Ymer,3)
            print("text ", "\"Mercury\"",r_Xmer+planets['Mercury']['Radius']*scale,r_Ymer)
        if "Venus" in planets:
            r_Venus=planets['Venus']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",x,y,r_Venus)
            r_Xven=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Venus']['Period'])*r_Venus
            r_Yven=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Venus']['Period'])*r_Venus
            print("fillcircle",r_Xven,r_Yven,3)
            print("text ", "\"Venus\"",r_Xven+planets['Venus']['Radius']*scale,r_Yven)
        if "Earth" in planets:
            r_Earth=planets['Earth']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",x,y,r_Earth)
            r_Xe=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Earth']['Period'])*r_Earth
            r_Ye=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Earth']['Period'])*r_Earth
            print("fillcircle",r_Xe,r_Ye,3)
            print("text ", "\"Earth\"",r_Xe+planets['Earth']['Radius']*scale,r_Ye)
        if "Moon" in planets:
            r_Moon=planets['Moon']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xe,r_Ye,r_Moon)
            r_Xm=r_Xe+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Moon']['Period'])*r_Moon
            r_Ym=r_Ye+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Moon']['Period'])*r_Moon
            print("fillcircle",r_Xm,r_Ym,3)
            print("text ", "\"Moon\"",r_Xm+planets['Moon']['Radius']*scale,r_Ym)
        if "Mars" in planets:
            r_Mars=planets['Mars']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",x,y,r_Mars)
            r_Xmar=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mars']['Period'])*r_Mars
            r_Ymar=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mars']['Period'])*r_Mars
            print("fillcircle",r_Xmar,r_Ymar,3)
            print("text ", "\"Mars\"",r_Xmar+planets['Mars']['Radius']*scale,r_Ymar)
        if "Phobos" in planets:
            r_Phobos=planets['Phobos']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xmar,r_Ymar,r_Phobos)
            r_Xpho=r_Xmar+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Phobos']['Period'])*r_Phobos
            r_Ypho=r_Ymar+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Phobos']['Period'])*r_Phobos
            print("fillcircle",r_Xpho,r_Ypho,3)
            print("text ", "\"Phobos\"",r_Xpho+planets['Phobos']['Radius']*scale,r_Ypho)
        if "Deimos" in planets:
            r_Deimos=planets['Deimos']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xmar,r_Ymar,r_Deimos)
            r_Xdei=r_Xmar+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Deimos']['Period'])*r_Deimos
            r_Ydei=r_Ymar+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Deimos']['Period'])*r_Deimos
            print("fillcircle",r_Xdei,r_Ydei,3)
            print("text ", "\"Deimos\"",r_Xpho+planets['Deimos']['Radius']*scale,r_Ydei)
        if "Ceres" in planets:
            r_Ceres=planets['Ceres']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",x,y,r_Ceres)
            r_Xcer=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ceres']['Period'])*r_Ceres
            r_Ycer=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ceres']['Period'])*r_Ceres
            print("fillcircle",r_Xcer,r_Ycer,3)
            print("text ", "\"Ceres\"",r_Xcer+planets['Ceres']['Radius']*scale,r_Ycer)
        if "Jupiter" in planets:
            r_Jupiter=planets['Jupiter']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",x,y,r_Jupiter)
            r_Xjup=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Jupiter']['Period'])*r_Jupiter
            r_Yjup=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Jupiter']['Period'])*r_Jupiter
            print("fillcircle",r_Xjup,r_Yjup,3)
            print("text ", "\"Jupiter\"",r_Xjup+planets['Jupiter']['Radius']*scale,r_Yjup)
        if "Io" in planets:
            r_Io=planets['Io']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xjup,r_Yjup,r_Io)
            r_Xio=r_Xjup+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Io']['Period'])*r_Io
            r_Yio=r_Yjup+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Io']['Period'])*r_Io
            print("fillcircle",r_Xio,r_Yio,3)
            print("text ", "\"Io\"",r_Xio+planets['Io']['Radius']*scale,r_Yio)
        if "Europa" in planets:
            r_Europa=planets['Europa']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xjup,r_Yjup,r_Europa)
            r_Xeur=r_Xjup+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Europa']['Period'])*r_Europa
            r_Yeur=r_Yjup+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Europa']['Period'])*r_Europa
            print("fillcircle",r_Xeur,r_Yeur,3)
            print("text ", "\"Europa\"",r_Xeur+planets['Europa']['Radius']*scale,r_Yeur)
        if "Ganymede" in planets:
            r_Ganymede=planets['Ganymede']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xjup,r_Yjup,r_Ganymede)
            r_Xgan=r_Xjup+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ganymede']['Period'])*r_Ganymede
            r_Ygan=r_Yjup+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ganymede']['Period'])*r_Ganymede
            print("fillcircle",r_Xgan,r_Ygan,3)
            print("text ", "\"Ganymede\"",r_Xgan+planets['Ganymede']['Radius']*scale,r_Ygan)
        if "Callisto" in planets:
            r_Callisto=planets['Callisto']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xjup,r_Yjup,r_Callisto)
            r_Xcal=r_Xjup+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Callisto']['Period'])*r_Callisto
            r_Ycal=r_Yjup+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Callisto']['Period'])*r_Callisto
            print("fillcircle",r_Xcal,r_Ycal,3)
            print("text ", "\"Callisto\"",r_Xcal+planets['Callisto']['Radius']*scale,r_Ycal)
        if "Saturn" in planets:
            r_Saturn=planets['Saturn']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",x,y,r_Saturn)
            r_Xsat=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Saturn']['Period'])*r_Saturn
            r_Ysat=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Saturn']['Period'])*r_Saturn
            print("fillcircle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,3)
            print("text ", "\"Saturn\"",r_Xsat+planets['Saturn']['Radius']*scale,r_Ysat)
        if "Mimas" in planets:
            r_Mimas=planets['Mimas']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Mimas)
            r_Xmim=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mimas']['Period'])*r_Mimas
            r_Ymim=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Mimas']['Period'])*r_Mimas
            print("fillcircle",r_Xmim,r_Ymim,3)
            print("text ", "\"Mimas\"",r_Xmim+planets['Mimas']['Radius']*scale,r_Ymim)
        if "Enceladus" in planets:
            r_Enceladus=planets['Enceladus']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Enceladus)
            r_Xenc=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Enceladus']['Period'])*r_Enceladus
            r_Yenc=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Enceladus']['Period'])*r_Enceladus
            print("fillcircle",r_Xenc,r_Yenc,3)
            print("text ", "\"Enceladus\"",r_Xenc+planets['Enceladus']['Radius']*scale,r_Yenc)
        if "Tethys" in planets:
            r_Tethys=planets['Tethys']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Tethys)
            r_Xtet=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Tethys']['Period'])*r_Tethys
            r_Ytet=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Tethys']['Period'])*r_Tethys
            print("fillcircle",r_Xtet,r_Ytet,3)
            print("text ", "\"Tethys\"",r_Xtet+planets['Tethys']['Radius']*scale,r_Ytet)
        if "Dione" in planets:
            r_Dione=planets['Dione']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Dione)
            r_Xdio=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Dione']['Period'])*r_Dione
            r_Ydio=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Dione']['Period'])*r_Dione
            print("fillcircle",r_Xdio,r_Ydio,3)
            print("text ", "\"Dione\"",r_Xdio+planets['Dione']['Radius']*scale,r_Ydio)
        if "Rhea" in planets:
            r_Rhea=planets['Rhea']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Rhea)
            r_Xrhe=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Rhea']['Period'])*r_Rhea
            r_Yrhe=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Rhea']['Period'])*r_Rhea
            print("fillcircle",r_Xrhe,r_Yrhe,3)
            print("text ", "\"Rhea\"",r_Xrhe+planets['Rhea']['Radius']*scale,r_Yrhe)
        if "Titan" in planets:
            r_Titan=planets['Titan']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Titan)
            r_Xtit=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titan']['Period'])*r_Titan
            r_Ytit=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titan']['Period'])*r_Titan
            print("fillcircle",r_Xtit,r_Ytit,3)
            print("text ", "\"Titan\"",r_Xtit+planets['Titan']['Radius']*scale,r_Ytit)
        if "Iapetus" in planets:
            r_Iapetus=planets['Iapetus']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xsat,r_Ysat,r_Iapetus)
            r_Xiap=r_Xsat+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Iapetus']['Period'])*r_Iapetus
            r_Yiap=r_Ysat+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Iapetus']['Period'])*r_Iapetus
            print("fillcircle",r_Xiap,r_Yiap,3)
            print("text ", "\"Iapetus\"",r_Xiap+planets['Iapetus']['Radius']*scale,r_Yiap)
        if "Uranus" in planets:
            r_Uranus=planets['Uranus']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",x,y,r_Uranus)
            r_Xura=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Uranus']['Period'])*r_Uranus
            r_Yura=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Uranus']['Period'])*r_Uranus
            print("fillcircle",r_Xura,r_Yura,3)
            print("text ", "\"Uranus\"",r_Xura+planets['Uranus']['Radius']*scale,r_Yura)
        if "Puck" in planets:
            r_Puck=planets['Puck']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Puck)
            r_Xpuc=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Puck']['Period'])*r_Puck
            r_Ypuc=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Puck']['Period'])*r_Puck
            print("fillcircle",r_Xpuc,r_Ypuc,3)
            print("text ", "\"Puck\"",r_Xpuc+planets['Puck']['Radius']*scale,r_Ypuc)
        if "Miranda" in planets:
            r_Miranda=planets['Miranda']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Miranda)
            r_Xmira=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Miranda']['Period'])*r_Miranda
            r_Ymira=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Miranda']['Period'])*r_Miranda
            print("fillcircle",r_Xmira,r_Ymira,3)
            print("text ", "\"Miranda\"",r_Xmira+planets['Miranda']['Radius']*scale,r_Ymira)
        if "Ariel" in planets:
            r_Ariel=planets['Ariel']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Ariel)
            r_Xari=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ariel']['Period'])*r_Ariel
            r_Yari=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Ariel']['Period'])*r_Ariel
            print("fillcircle",r_Xari,r_Yari,3)
            print("text ", "\"Ariel\"",r_Xari+planets['Ariel']['Radius']*scale,r_Yari)
        if "Umbriel" in planets:
            r_Umbriel=planets['Umbriel']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Umbriel)
            r_Xumb=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Umbriel']['Period'])*r_Umbriel
            r_Yumb=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Umbriel']['Period'])*r_Umbriel
            print("fillcircle",r_Xumb,r_Yumb,3)
            print("text ", "\"Umbriel\"",r_Xumb+planets['Umbriel']['Radius']*scale,r_Yumb)
        if "Titania" in planets:
            r_Titania=planets['Titania']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Titania)
            r_Xtita=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titania']['Period'])*r_Titania
            r_Ytita=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titania']['Period'])*r_Titania
            print("fillcircle",r_Xtita,r_Ytita,3)
            print("text ", "\"Titania\"",r_Xtita+planets['Titania']['Radius']*scale,r_Ytita)
        if "Oberon" in planets:
            r_Oberon=planets['Oberon']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xura,r_Yura,r_Oberon)
            r_Xober=r_Xura+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Oberon']['Period'])*r_Oberon
            r_Yober=r_Yura+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Oberon']['Period'])*r_Oberon
            print("fillcircle",r_Xober,r_Yober,3)
            print("text ", "\"Oberon\"",r_Xober+planets['Oberon']['Radius']*scale,r_Yober)
        if "Neptune" in planets:
            r_Neptune=planets['Neptune']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",x,y,r_Neptune)
            r_Xnep=x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Neptune']['Period'])*r_Neptune
            r_Ynep=y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Neptune']['Period'])*r_Neptune
            print("fillcircle",r_Xnep,r_Ynep,3)
            print("text ", "\"Neptune\"",r_Xnep+planets['Neptune']['Radius']*scale,r_Ynep)
        if "Titan" in planets:
            r_Titan=planets['Titan']['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle",r_Xnep,r_Ynep,r_Titan)
            r_Xtita=r_Xnep+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titan']['Period'])*r_Titan
            r_Ytita=r_Ynep+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets['Titan']['Period'])*r_Titan
            print("fillcircle",r_Xtita,r_Ytita,3)
            print("text ", "\"Titan\"",r_Xtita+planets['Titan']['Radius']*scale,r_Ytita)

        t += 0.003
        draw(x, y, t, planets)
```

Again, you probably want a working base case to stop your recursion at some point.

BTW, if you want to clean up your print statements, here's a way to iterate through your planets (use it or leave it):

```
for p in planets.keys():
    planet = planets[p]
```

I don't know if that's useful or not, just maybe might save you some typing.

Comment: just putting the draw inside the function doesnt seem to work

Comment: Did you remove your while(true) and align it properly (draw() should be called in the else: or outside it but inside the def

Comment: i just edited the question it looks like that but isnt workin?

Comment: did you de-dent the code inside `else` afterwards?

Comment: yeah i jus pasted yours and it didnt work

Comment: was there an error? can you be a bit more descriptive?

Comment: there was no output to quickdraw

Comment: derp. did you call draw(x,y,t, planets) anywhere?

Comment: yeah at the end??? just like above

Comment: any help would be great my assignments due in like 30mins

Answer (score 3):

You can you something like this:

```
def draw_e(x, y, t, planets):
    if 'Satellites' in planets["Moon"]:
        print ("fillcircle", x, y, planets["Moon"]['Radius']*scale)
    else:
        print("refresh")
        print("colour 0 0 0")
        print("clear")
        print("colour 255 255 255")
        print("fillcircle",x,y,planets['Sun']['Radius']*scale)
        print("text ", "\"Sun\"",x+planets['Sun']['Radius']*scale,y)

        for each in planets.keys():
            r_planet=planets[each]['Orbital Radius']*scale;
            print("circle", x, y, r_Mercury)
            r_X = x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets[each]['Period'])*r_planet
            r_Y = y+math.cos(t*2*math.pi/planets[each]['Period'])*r_planet
            print("fillcircle",r_X,r_Y,3)

            print("text ", each, r_X+planets[each]['Radius']*scale,r_Y)

            t += 0.003

draw(x, y, t, planets)
```

Comment: Your code seems to be misaligned.

Comment: you're right, fixed now.

Comment: when i run the above i get this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a43.py", line 60, in <module>
    draw_e(x, y, t, planets)
  File "a43.py", line 53, in draw_e
    r_X = x+math.sin(t*2*math.pi/planets[each]['Period'])*r_planet
KeyError: 'Period'

Comment: still misaligned, I would edit but it needs more chars to accept edit

Comment: @Rustem im not sure what the problem is

Comment: @nair.ashvin do you know what is causin the key error?

Comment: Still misaligned! @tomsmith I do not know why the KeyError happens. Are you sure your original code works?

Comment: Your planet dictinary seems like incorrect, Try this code http://pastebin.com/LRhdY0G0

Comment: the really long one works perfectly

Comment: @Rustem i get a error for syntax when coming to the modulus part

Comment: @Rustem this part   except:
                print 'Planet %s falled' % each
                # raise

Comment: @nair.ashvin what do you man its misaligned?

Comment: can anyone help on this one!!!!! it seems great to clean all my if's i just KeyError: 'Period'

Comment: Does every planet have a Period?

Comment: Too bad this function isn't recursive...it could be made so by realizing that to the sun the planets are satellites and thse satellites may have satellites of their own.